# How often does peercoin minting pay out?

Tags: altcoin, proof-of-stake, peercoin

If I have a peercoin wallet and generate coins with the PoS system, how often does it pay me the 1%? Can I change this to every week/month/half year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minting is random. There is no guarantee that you will get 1% in a year, you could get 0% or 75%. You will get them when you successfully mint a block.

Comment: So is it just mining?